# after adding a ViewController.swift and renaming it won't link my viewController with that swift class

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I had created new swift file `myviewController.swift`  and before linking to my view controller, I had renamed it to `newController.swift`. Yet it is not showing in the identity inspector to link the class to my view controller.

I tried adding it directly to the project folder but it says that newController.swift file already exists.

Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

Comment: Did you renamed the `class` name from within the file?

Comment: no, after closing the class file. Only storyboard was open!

Comment: try selecting another class and them reselecting it

Comment: oops. I didn't change the class name, just the file name. Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The list of classes populated in your Interface Builder is based on the class names and not the file names.  Single files can hold multiple classes.

In addition to changing the file name, you need to also change the class name if you want the class name to be different in Interface Builder and other locations.

If, after changing the class name, it still does not appear in Interface Builder, try building your project by pressing Cmd+B, and looking again.

---

Consider the following file:

#### ViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class FooController: UIViewController {
    //stuff
}

class BarController: UIViewController {
    // stuff
}
```

Despite the file being named `ViewController.swift`, `ViewController` will not appear in the drop down list for my view controllers.

Instead, I get default, built in `UIKit` view controllers, and the two controllers I defined in this file, `FooController`, and `BarController`:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Renaming the file in Swift 2.1, XCode 7 , iOS9 is done in **3 steps**:

**Step 1 :** **Rename the file itself**
eg: From the default 'ViewController.swift' to 'MyViewController.swift'. Make sure you keep the have the 'ViewController' text appended( in this case to 'My'. thats the Standard.

**Step 2:** Within the file, **change the name of the Class**
eg: From the default 'Class ViewController : UIViewController' to 'Class MyViewController : UIViewController'

**Step 3:** In the main storyboard, click/select on the scene/ViewController (make sure you got blue border). Go to the **Identity Inspector** in the right menu, under the 'Custom Class' section, **the 'Class'  dropdown should now have the new name** i.e 'MyViewController'. Just select it.

Clean the project so that the same is refreshed.

Comment: Remeber to edit the extensions to the ViewController, i.e., extension: MyViewController

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure you connect your code to your view controller class.

The name of your file doesn't matter as long as you select the right view controller .

You have to select your view controller and them select, using the identity  inspector, the custom class you created using the pull down menu (NewViewController).

```
class NewViewController : UIViewController {
    // your code    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3 using Xcode 8:**

**Step 1:** Open project navigator in Navigation panel. Click on the file you want to rename.

[image: Click on the file]

**Step 2:** Open File inspector in Utilities Panel. Change the name of the file and press return.

[image: Change the name]

**Step 3:** Change the name of the class in your file.

[image: Change name of the class]

**Step 4:** Open your storyboard and select the corresponding view.

[image: Select the view]

**Step 5:** Open Identity inspector in Utilities panel. Change the name of the class. Press return.

[image: Change the name of class]

**Additional Step (if still doesn't work):** Quit Xcode and open again. This a bug in Xcode which I face frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you renamed your VC from terminal using MV command, then you can still see the old file reference in the Project in xcode [In red colour]. Just delete the old file from there as well, otherwise you will get the same error when you build your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your project root directory. The file will be there you can delete the unwanted file from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search and delete  in project globally
2. Force Quit Xcode
3. Control click -> on .xcodeproj/xcworkspace -> Show Package Contents
4. Remove xcuserdata directory
5. Run .xcodeproj/xcworkspace